# Which test should I use for a proportion of a categorical variable in one sample?

Tags: categorical-data, t-test

I was wondering which test I should use to compare two proportions in one sample?
My research is about white matter hyperintensities (WMH) in migraine compared to tension-type headache. There are three options: only deep WMH (63,6%), only periventricular WHM (6,1%) or both (30,3%). I want to know if there are more 'only deep'WMH compared to only periventricular WMH (only for migraine). I've a small sample (N=33). Can I use an one sample t-test?

Thank you in advance

Indeed pv+both and deep+both but how can I compare 33 patients with 12 pv and 31 deep to each other? Also with binominal?

Comment: A one-sample t-test is used to compare a sample mean with a specified mean. Since your dealing with proportions the answer is no. I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to compare but it sounds like a job for a test of independence or Fisher exact test

Comment: Thank you. I want to compare deep WMH (63,6%) to periventricular WMH (6,1%) in the group with migraine. I came across this site http://www.statpac.com/statistics-calculator/percents.htm, so that's why I thought I could use an one-sample t-test

Comment: I stand (partly) corrected. Apparently people use t-test although not completely appropriate. Still given that there are three possibilities instead of two, I'm unsure whether a t-test is really appropriate. Perhaps [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58930/how-to-compare-percentages-for-two-categories-from-one-sample) is more what you're looking for

Comment: Maybe a chi square goodness of fit is appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 p-WMH and 21 d-WMH. Under assumption of equal probability of being p- or d-WMH, it should follow binomial distribution Bin(0.5, 23). Under this null hypothesis, the probability of getting 2 or less cases in p-WMH is 3.3 x $10^{-5}$. Same for 2 or less cases in d-WMH. So the p-value is 6.6 x $10^{-5}$.

Conclusion: Reject the null hypothesis and support the idea that the chances to be p- or d-WMH are not the same.

This method utilizes the symmetry of the binomial distribution when event probability is 0.5. So if the null hypothesis **is not** event probability = 0.5, this method will give you wrong answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question because there are patients who have both. So migraine (N = 33): in total there are 12 patients with periventricular and 31  patients have deep.. can I also use binominal distribution  (0.5) ? Should I use n=43?

Comment: My answer is based on "if there are more 'only deep'WMH compared to only periventricular WMH (only for migraine)." For this question both-WMH dose not provide any useful information, so just exclude them. If you add both-WMH into question as group, you get the multinomial distribution. The idea that leads to n=43 is unacceptable, because sample size cannot be changed.

Comment: Which test should I use because 31 patients have deep and 12 have periventricular of the 33 patients? I hope you understand what I mean because my first question was the difference to only deep versus only periventricular

Comment: From you data, you can work on the probabilities of p-WMH, d-WMH and both-WMH. Your first question is p-WMH = d-WMH or not. We already have the answer. It seems your second question is: If p-WMH + both-WMH = d-WMH + both-WMH. If my understanding is correct, the second question = first question, because subtracting both-WMH in both sides of the equation in second question leads to the first question. If my understanding is incorrect, please give the more explanation in terms of that three probabilities.

Comment: Indeed pv+both and deep+both but how can I compare 33 patients with 12 pv and 31 deep to each other? Also with binominal?

Comment: No.1: 12 + 31 = 43 > 33 of sample size. So no more binomial. 2: pv+both vs deep+both <=> pv vs deep, so I cannot understand the meaning of comparing 12 pv vs 31 deep. What is the scientific issue (not statistical one) you want to resolve?

Comment: If there is a difference between total deep and total periventricular. So 31 and 12. And i also wanted to know only pv and only deep which you already explained really clear to me (thanks)

Comment: I finally understand why it is the same question. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: So it is finished?

Comment: I added a sentence in the Answer. Maybe you need to see it.

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a difference so I used event probability of 0.5

Comment: That sentence is for warning.